# Plotting a scatter but doesn't show

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am plotting in python but the scatter plot doesn't show?
What am I doing wrong

[Scatter plot and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h9jF.jpg)

can someone help me?
thanks!

Comment: You need to use the arguments that are expected by `plt.plot`, not some `plt.plot(argument_I_just_invented="something")`. Note that a scatter plot is produced with `plt.scatter`.

Comment: I think you are confusing the plot command by `pandas` with the one by `pyplot`.

Answer (score 2):

1. plot does not have any parameter name `type`
2. To plot the scatter use `plt.scatter(x,y)`